# #ant eclipse floodlight.xml [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource tasks.properties. It could not be found

Tags: eclipse, ant, sdn, mininet

I am trying to build floodlight using #ant eclipse command. But it is showing an error :

Buildfile: /home/mamata/floodlight/build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource tasks.properties. It could not be found.

init:

eclipse:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second

And if I open eclipse and import floodlight project. It shows 44 warnings. In run configuration I cannot find FloodlightLaunch.

Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

follow thiese steps

INSTALL THE FLOODLIGHT OPENFLOW SDN CONTROLLER

The following is from the FloodLight Wiki Installation Guide. It’s perfect so no need to rewrite it.

1
2
3
4
5
6

sudo apt-get install build-essential default-jdk ant python-dev eclipse
git clone git://github.com/floodlight/floodlight.git
cd floodlight
ant eclipse

Open eclipse and create a new workspace (inside Eclipse) :

./eclipse & <-Non-root from the command line or find the icon to launch it Eclipse.
File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace. Then click “Next”.
From “Select root directory” click “Browse”. Select the parent directory where you placed floodlight earlier.
Check the box for “Floodlight”. No other Projects should be present and none should be selected.
Click Finish.
Create the FloodlightLaunch target (inside Eclipse):

Click Run->Run Configurations
Right Click Java Application->New
For Name use FloodlightLaunch
For Project use Floodlight
For Main use net.floodlightcontroller.core.Main
Click Apply
click run 
and your are good to go